# Why Getting Http Request and Response too late

Tags: c#, .net, performance, http, buffer

I am using http post method to send request to a Http Server URL.

Time difference between request and response is around 60 seconds but as per Server team they are sending response withing 7 seconds once request reached at their end.

I don't think network is taking remaining 53 seconds of time to reach packet at server end, so what can be the issue.

In this application we are using synchronous communication in between client and server. Kindly provide me following details also.

1. Is it due to server is sending request at more speed than server is
   able to handle. In this case many times client is getting request at
   interval of 3 seconds whereas server is taking 7 seconds to handle
   this.
2. What is network buffer. Whether there are two buffers at network
   level one at client place and other at server place.
3. If server is unable to handle request at same speed what client is
   sending is all request get buffered at client buffer and what  will
   happen if more request are pending to be processed than maximum size
   of that buffer.
4. What are alternative way to improve performance if we are at client
   end and no control on server

EDIT : When I used wireshark in my network to capture network logs I found that it is appearning in wireshark 20 seconds after actually my application is send to Server. What is reason behind this delay. what can be the possible reason in which request is appearing in network 20 seconds delay from actually it has been sent.

Comment: What consist of 60 seconds , is it throughput?

Comment: Fiddler (http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) is your friend..download this and fire it up, it will provide you with HTTP time statistics that will allow you to diagnose the problem better

Comment: It is time difference between sending request to server and getting response from server

Comment: Try to ping your server. Second question, what is volume of data in response?

Comment: Try and break down the problem.  Time your client code against local host to see how much time is spent preparing the response, also figure out the message sizes.  This will help others answer where your problem is

Comment: Also consider the possibility that the server is sending data immediately, but it is taking a long time to close it's connection (ie [Long Polling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29)).

Comment: Where was the Wireshark capture taken from? The client machine?

Comment: What is the size of the data for a typical/average request and response? Also it will help to know the nature of these data. 7 seconds is a lot of time for http servers, but it also may be the time needed to start a response and not to complete it.

Comment: Ashish, stating your app is using synchronous communication between client and server does not help since HTTP runs over TCP which is inherently synchronous. It will be more helpful if you can tell whether the request goes through a Wide Area Network to reach the server machine or, if it's all (server and client) at Local Area Network level, in which case there's less chance for delays to happen or they would be very very negligible.

Comment: This can help too, specially if your HTTP server is across a WAN. Try www.speedtest.net to figure out your Internet connection speed (commonly known as bandwidth), download speed as well as upload speed, and network latency (number of milliseconds given by ping). Typically the download speed is greater than the upload speed by a factor of 2 or 3.

Comment: If the server is setup to send chunked responses it could be sending the headers and some of the body out but then it gets "stuck" working on a large task.  In PHP this is demonstrated by: <?php echo "started"; sleep(60); echo "ended"; ?> You would see the started immediately but then the ended a minute later if the server was setup in chunked mode.

Comment: You gotta give us some code to analyze. Your question is too open to interpretations. How exactly are you sending the HTTP requests and response each peer? I had similar problem a couple years ago and I'm quite sure what your problem is, but explaining this without knowing if it is actually the same mistake it is a shot in the dark.

Comment: @AshishKhandelwal based on this: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/10073904#10073904 Do you still need help?

Answer (score 33):

In regards to your edit, to help you understand.  Networking follows a model called *Open Source Intercommunication (OSI)*.  This model is broken down into seven distinct layers, all with a function.

Those layers are here:

[image: OSI Model]

Wireshark detects *packets* which are located at Layer 3.  Which is handled by a *Router*. The *Network Interface Card (NIC)* takes the allotted data and turns it into a *packet* to send across the wire.

Wireshark won't detect the packet until your *NIC* has converted it into a *packet* in which a *Router* handles.

You see once it is converted into a *packet* it contains the following information:

- 4 Bits that contain the version (IPV4 or IPV6)
- 4 Bits that contain the Internet Header.
- 8 Bits that contain the *Type Of Service* or the *Quality Of Service* and priority.
- 16 Bits that contain the length of the packet in Bytes.
- 16 Bits that contain the identification tag to help **Reconstruct the packet from Fragments**.
- 3 Bits, the first is a zero followed by a flag that says to allow Fragment or Not. And quantity.
- 13 Bits that contain the Fragment offset, field to identify the position to original.
- 8 Bits that contain the *Time To Live (TTL)* and *Hops across Routers*.
- 8 Bits that contain the Protocol (TCP, UDP, ICMP, etc.)
- 16 Bits that contain the *Header Checksum*
- 32 Bits that contain the Source IP Address
- 32 Bits that contain the Destination IP Address

Those are the key 160 Bits that are created when creating such a packet.

**What does this mean?**

Well, you know that it takes twenty seconds for *Wireshark* to detect your packet.  So right off the bat we know it took your application twenty seconds to actually build this packet.

Which we know the Server will also need to **Reconstruct** this packet so that it can handle the data and possibly send off a request.

We also know that the *Router* is acting like a traffic cop, sending your data across the internet or local network.

**Well, that adds quite a bit of inference? But where do I go?**

You have a utility called: **tracert**

On average it takes a route request one to two milliseconds to pass through five to six foot cable, so if it generates the initial hop one or two milliseconds, but the second hop is triggered in twenty-thirty milliseconds then you could use a simple formula:

```
6 * 20
```

Based on the current speed from our **tracert** we can estimate the time duration.  This is a very generic approach but tools exists for exact accuracy. But the more hops, the more time it will take to reach the destination. Also the more you'll multiply.

**What about that in between from Client to Server?**

- Local Area Networks (LAN) : The internal efficiency of a network is due to the optimizations of each Network Protocol, Equipment, and Physical Median.  A Network Administrator has to measure reliability with speed; as well as all the traffic generated by the Network.  So an equipments throughput and physical median are important.  You wouldn't want a ten cars merging into a one lane tunnel, that could create a bottle neck same applies for a Network.
- Wide Area Network (WAN) : This essentially is the connection to the Internet, the Cloud. Think of it like this:  Your computer is on a LAN, the Router goes to a WAN.  Then your ISP more then likely has a LAN which then has it's WAN open up to a larger distribution facility.  It keeps working it's way up until it reaches the internet.

**What can I do though?**

You know what is in between now, but what can I do?

Well, when your generating your *Service* you obviously want to ensure your code is lean and highly efficient.  As efficiency can be crucial in speed.  So altering buffer sizes, transmission rates, and etc.  can greatly improve your application.

Obviously good code practice will help.

**My code is rock solid though?**

If you believe your code isn't the problem at this point, or the method in which you *Host* and *Create your Service* then these factors may be the cause:

- Local Machine may be generating excessive chatter, so it takes quite a bit longer.
- Local Network is generating excessive chatter or inefficient / low throughput.
- Your request is traveling long distance, so the time is delayed.
- Your Internet Service Provider may have Hardware Firewalls, Proxies, and so on that scan these packets.
- Your Server may have excessive request or the Host method isn't efficient.

Those are a larger chunk of variables.  All you can try is to refactor the Service and ensure your Server is hosting it the most efficient way possible.  Otherwise you'll want to get a Information Technology Team involved it is critical.

But keep this in mind, your experience may be better or worst then another clients with interfacing with this service.

I'm speaking under the assumption your deployed in one location and you could be several states away from your Server.

*Tools:*

Command Line:

- Ping
- Tracert

Network and Protocol Analyzers:

- Fiddler (HTTP/HTTPS) : See if Fiddler displays any HTTP Status Codes for Troubleshooting.
- Wireshark : Will analyze your network traffic which can help time durations.

There are other utilities available to actually mitigate and test Network Speeds even to other locations, just Google "Network Tools".  Fluke has a few.

Hopefully that explains why it may take twenty seconds for Wireshark to even display the packet on the Network.

Hope that helps.

Comment: +1 for the hard (and amazing :)) work, also might add http://serverfault.com/questions/10235/what-is-the-osi-model-and-how-does-it-apply-to-todays-networks...

Comment: @NadavBen-Gal Thank you.  That is a nice post as well.

Answer (score 8):

Use Wireshark to capture your request and response 60 seconds apart on the wire, and send it to the server team.  They may respond with a capture showing the request and response closer to 7 seconds on their side.  That's great! Send them both to the network team.

On the other hand, it's possible that the trace shows that the delay is in your code.  There may be some kind of throttling or delay on your end that keeps the request from leaving your process for a significant amount of time.  A Wireshark trace can tell you that, also.

Comment: yep. this sounds like a job for wireshark not fiddler.

Comment: Well the OP should be able to examine the capture himself first - he should try to work out what's wrong before passing it on to another team.

Comment: @bmm6o Nice response, yeah.  That will alleviate code or server related issues and point him directly to the Networks as a potential issue.

Answer (score 7):

TCP/IP stream will control most of the stuff you are worried about.

**"Sending request faster than the server can't handle"**

No you will never send anything to the server faster than it can receive when using a TCP session. The transmission flow is guided and impossible  to send faster than the server can handle.

**"What is network buffer"**

There are two queue buffers envolved in the TCP/IP communication, a send buffer and a receive buffer.

When you make a `send()` call, it doesn't really send anything, it will just queue the data in the send buffer, and will return to you how many of the bytes you were trying to send were actually put into the queue for sending. If it return less than you were trying to send, it means you have to wait before sending the rest because the buffer is full.

This is how you control the traffic, it is your cue to know if you are trying to send stuff too fast. Try to keep the buffer full as long as you have data to send, but don't ignore the fact that not everything will fit in the buffer and you have to retry later.

The `recv()` also has its own buffer. This command is not actually to receive anything, the data is already received, `recv()` will only read it from the receive buffer. When using a blocking socket (default), `recv()` will hang if the buffer is empty, waiting for new data to arrive. `recv()` will only return 0 if the connection was terminated or if you try to use it with a non-blocking socket.

If you forget to `recv()` and the receive buffer becomes full, it is okay too. The peer will be unable to continue sending, as `send()` will start to return 0 to them, but as long you pay attention to the `send()` return value no data is lost at any time.

As far as I know, the buffer size is 64KB in all systems by default, both for sending or receiving. There are commands to adjust this buffer size, but it is not interesting to mess with. If you need a bigger buffer, make it in your application.

**"What are alternative way to improve performance if we are at client end and no control on server"**

Its not exactly a valid question, you cannot do that. I think you might be doing some mistake with the HTTP requests, specially considering you are doing POST requests.

When doing a POST request, your HTTP header will contain two headers that are usually only seen on server HTTP response headers: The Content-Type and Content-Length. They are very important when doing a POST, and if one of them is missing or wrong, the HTTP session may hang for a couple seconds or not succeed at all.

Another important aspect of HTTP, is the most essential difference between HTTP 1.0 and HTTP 1.1: HTTP 1.0 does not support *Keep-Alive*. It is easier for a beginner to deal with HTTP 1.0, because with HTTP 1.0, you connect, send your request, the server answers and the connection is terminated, meaning you finished downloading the server response. With HTTP 1.1 it will not happen by default. The connection remains open until it times out. You have to pay attention to the HTTP response header Content-Length and count bytes in order to know if the server concluded sending the stuff you requested.

It is also important to observe that not all servers support HTTP 1.0. You may make a HTTP 1.0 request, but it will respond with 1.1 anyway, with Keep-Alives and all stuff you wasn't expecting. On a perfect world it shouldn't happen, but it does.

Your mistake might be around in this area. Sinse you said your request is taking exactly 60 seconds, I suspect it is because its timing out. You probably already received everything you had to, but the application is not handling that properly and than hangs until the connection is terminated by the server.

Answer (score 2):

On point number 1:

In your point number 1 I believe you meant to say '1. Is it due to CLIENT sending....' and 'In this case many times client is getting RESPONSE at interval....'.

On point number 3:

- The server machine is typically a more powerful computer than the client machine so this "If server is unable to handle request at same speed what client is sending" is very rarely the case. If I remember right, HTTP server goes by "first come first serve" and what you are calling request buffer would be a queue on the server side not the client. I have never heard of "all request get buffered at client buffer".
- The time server takes to response is usually fast but the time result takes to come back to you, the client, has more to do with what the original request is doing, whether it's only retrieving a static html file, or retrieving a big image or document, or having to execute a heavy query on the DB server, etc.
- Are you the only client submitting HTTP requests to the server? Probably not. Is that server machine housing only the HTTP server? Remember the server is or will be handling requests from multiple clients and this could be another factor for delayed response sometimes, even when the server can handle multiple request simultaneously and depending on what those other requests are doing. The extreme example of an HTTP server unable to respond because of multiple requests is when the server is under a [distributed] denial of service attack.
- Do you have any firewalls protecting the HTTP server or protecting the network where the HTTP server resides?? Having firewall rules or network intrusion detection systems can delay the request/response time.
- The following could be another factor for "what can be the possible reason in which request is appearing in network 20 seconds delay from actually it has been sent." It is called 'network congestion' and typically happens at the router level.

On point number 4:

- Once you discard or eliminate factors related to point 3, you can improve performance by:
- First, all else not being a [major] factor of delay, figure out what is your expectated response time.
- Second, make sure you have a reasonable accurate measure of the time the round trip is taking under what conditions/circumstances. I would assume the HTTP server is not to blame.
- Third, if still experiencing delay, you (or someone else) will need look at router's configuration, firewalls configuration, and your html page code if any or your web application if any.

Edit:

Try pinging your HTTP server to know the network roundtrip time.

Here's an example; I did submit this command:

> **`ping www.yahoo.com`**

from an MS-DOS window on the client PC.

[image]

1) Notice how round-trip takes aprox 0.5 seconds or less (0.5 seconds = 500 ms). I'm in the US East coast, Yahoo.com is likely to be on the US West cost (I'm not sure).

2) Notice every round-trip is not always same length, but variation is small.

3) From my local PC to a world class exposed server like Yahoo.com, there are several requests, routers, and firewalls in between and the response time was not even 1 second. This means network and server are rarely the cause of a delay if they are properly configured, which means your page or application should be examined/reviewed thoroughly before blaming it on the HTTP server.

4) When I submit request http://www.yahoo.com from my browser, loading the page sure took a little more than 0.5 second, I think because of all the html elements and ads in the page but the HTTP server response was likely 0.5 second.

Comment: Windows doesn't use DOS, it's called the Command Line now. Also some Networks have ICMP request blocked it is better to use Tracert because it will fail at that given Router but show all other time and hops to destination.

Answer (score 0):

On point # 4 : For large volumes of data the amount of time spent in the wire can be significant. If your server supports it you may want to compress the contents before you send it across.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check your DNS configuration, I think it could be a problem. Before your browser or script make a request is necessary to resolve domain name to ip address.

You can easliy check this by adding additional information to your host file which is located in windows:

C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

or in linux system:

\etc\hosts

To check information about domain and ip address try to use nslookup (the same command on Windows and Linux OS)